# How to redirect http request to https on java application installed on Amazon ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: jakarta-ee, https, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I am using Amazon ElasticBeanstalk for my Java EE web application deployment.
I want my application should be https only so i have configured SSL certificate on ElasticLoadbalancer.
also i have configured web.xml file as

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>HTTPSOnly</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>      
    <user-data-constraint>      
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
```

But the problem is when i hit http://www.myweb.com then it redirect to http://www.myweb.com:8443 so i want to remove the port from url
Amazon EBS & Load balancer working explained as below
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I also went down the path of adding the securityConstraint in my web.xml. With the stock server.xml that EB deploys with your application however you get a redirct to port 8443. You can edit this file by hand but it gets blown away on your next deployment. Research suggested including a .ebextensions file in the deployment war that would overwrite the server.xml file but this runs the risk of AWS changing something else in server.xml in the future. Another issue is I want the same app version (build from jenkins) to work in my dev environment as well as other EB environments that don't necessarily need/have ssl enabled.

So I changed course and implemented a servlet filter which uses two headers that the load balancer provides

- X-Forwarded-Proto
- x-forwarded-host

if X-Forward-Proto == http then you know you need to forward, x-forward-host is needed to construct the full url for redirection (as least that's how I ended up doing it). Here is the filter with environment specific control over it using a customer PropertiesHelper

```
public class RedirectFilter implements Filter {
    boolean firstTime = true;
    boolean redirect = false;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        if (firstTime) {
            PropertiesHelper propertiesHelper = SpringApplicationContext.getPropertiesHelper();
            redirect = propertiesHelper.getBooleanProperty("redirectHttp");
            firstTime = false;
        }

        if (!redirect) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        String protocol = req.getHeader("X-Forwarded-Proto");
        if (null != protocol && protocol.equals("http")) {
            String host = req.getHeader("x-forwarded-host");
            String requestURI = req.getRequestURI();
            String redirectUrl = "https://" + host + requestURI;

            res.sendRedirect(redirectUrl);
            return;
        }
        chain.doFilter(req, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

You enable the filter with entries in the web.xml, making sure it is in the proper order with other filters you have

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>httpsRedirectFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.cars.platform.util.RedirectFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>httpsRedirectFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Lastly you do need to enable both http and https (port 443) on the load balancer

Comment: It works great, I made it work within a grails application. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you only want the standard HTTPS port 443 to be used by the [Elastic Load Balancer](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) and not the additionally configure port 8443?

This is easily possible by clicking the *Remove* button int he *Action* column within the listener table of the first image you provided. The entire process, including options to achieve the same goal by different means, is also detailed and illustrated in [Deleting a Listener from Your Load Balancer](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/us-delete-listener.html):

> The following sections include instructions for deleting a listener
>   from the specified port of your existing load balancer using the AWS
>   Management Console, command line interface (CLI), or the Query API. In
>   this example, you delete a listener from port 80 of your load balancer
>   MyLoadBalancer.

Comment: I agree with your answer. But the problem with that case is:
Amazon attached ec2 instance with every elasticbeanstalk app.
so when i accessed that instance (actual machine running tomcat) then i found tomcat server.xml file having defauly ports 80 & 8443.
the code which i have written in web.xml will change request to https://www.myweb.com:8443/ here the problem how can i remove this port from url

Comment: Is there any way amazon provide for Elastic load balancer port (8443)redirect to another elastic load balancer port(443)

Answer (score 0):

I caught the same problem, tried googling but without luck, finally I got the answer.

Before things goes fine, I have the following port redirection settings:

```
redirect 192.168.1.177:80 to 127.0.0.1:8080  
redirect 192.168.1.177:443 to 127.0.0.1:8443
```

And there in web.xml is such a piece of code:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>SecuredResources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

When I was visiting `http://192.168.1.177/`, Tomcat redirected the request to `https://192.168.1.177:8443/` which is not the one `https://192.168.1.177/` as I expected.

I found that there is a attribute `redirectPort` of element `<Connector/>` in  server.xml, When I tried setting the `redirectPort` to `443` of HTTP connector,

from

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

to

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="443"/>
```

then after restarting Tomcat, voilà, it works.